# Amazon SQS message parsing using python + boto

Tags: python, amazon-sqs

I am using boto library to read messages from SQS queue. My messages have text like this:
`{ Command:XXXXXXXXXXX Key:XXXXXXX Input:XXXXXX}` . Boto sends with base64 encoded and also reads it, so that if I read the message body then the text is there. 
But how can I read the message like

```
Command = input['Command'] 
Key = input_message['Key'].split(',')
```

so that I can use those values for further processing...

I am quite new to Python also

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you seem to have the input in some kind of a format - is it anything standardised? If not, you would need to parse the contents of your message and get the individual keys.

What I have been doing before in my projects was using [JSON](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to facilitate data exchange between platforms.

If you do not have a luxury to edit your incoming data, you would need to do something like this (very naiive example):

```
input = "{ Command:XXXXXXXXXXX Key:XXXXXXX Input:XXXXXX }"
data = filter(lambda x: ":" in x, input.split())
message_dict = dict()
for item in data:
    key, val = item.split(":")
    message_dict[key] = val
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using good old fashioned JSON to easily send and receive dictionaries acrost the wire.

This test function verifies that the data format is very clear with JSON:

## test_sqs.py

```
import json

import boto3
from moto import mock_sqs

@mock_sqs
def test_sqs():
    sqs = boto3.resource('sqs', 'us-east-1')
    queue = sqs.create_queue(QueueName='votes')

    queue.send_message(MessageBody=json.dumps(
        {'Command': 'drink', 'Key': 'beer', 'Input': 'tasty'}))

    messages = queue.receive_messages()
    assert len(messages) == 1
    assert messages[0].body == (
        '{"Input": "tasty", "Command": "drink", "Key": "beer"}')
```